# How to extract an HTML full link from a string?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract an Html link from a string. I tried using patterns and matcher to find the link but my regex is wrong. I only want to get the cloneurlHttp : Any help to fix this?

And this string is not in JSon.

```
     String s = "{RepositoryMetadata: {AccountId: 329791006272,RepositoryId: 425f5fc5-18d8-4ae5-b1a8-55eb9cf72bef,RepositoryName: CodeCommitTest,DefaultBranch: master,LastModifiedDate: Tue Oct 20 13:50:57 ACDT 2015,CreationDate: Tue Oct 13 16:36:03 ACDT 2015,CloneUrlHttp: https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/CodeCommitTest,CloneUrlSsh: ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/CodeCommitTest,Arn: arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:329791006272:CodeCommitTest}}";

    String pattern = "^\\CloneURLHttp:\\s(.*?)$";
    String httpaddress = "";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m;



        m = r.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            httpaddress = m.group(1);

        }


    System.out.println(httpaddress);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundaries and negated charcter class.

```
String pattern = "(?i)\\bCloneURLHttp:\\s*([^,]*)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m;
m = r.matcher(s);
String httpaddress = "";
if (m.find()) {
        httpaddress = m.group(1);
 }
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wU5aL3/1)